# NSTimer Array?? returns out of range

Tags: ios, swift

```
var multiTimer: [NSTimer] = []
```

I have tried using

```
multiTimer[indexPath.row] = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
            target: self, selector: "TargetFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It returns array out of range...

Comment: What is the index path and what else is in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You have to append NSTimer to `multiTimer`

```
multiTimer.append(NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
        target: self, selector: "TargetFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably what you're after is an array containing optional timers, pre-populated with nil so you can later add timers on demand:

```
var multiTimer: [NSTimer?] = []

// add a loop to initialise your array with nil entries for each index path (pseudo code)

For i, multiTimer[i] = nil

// now you can replace the nil at any index with an initialised timer
multiTimer[indexPath.row] = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
        target: self, selector: "TargetFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```